# Prove that for any partition  of [,], (f,)=0.

Tags: riemann-integration, upper-lower-bounds

Let < and consider the function F:[,]→ℝ given by

F()=

```
   0  if  ≤  <

   1  if  =
```

Prove that for any partition  of [,], (F,)=0.

Hello, can anyone help me with this question? Much help needed. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I am completely lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one, observe that with $b = x_n \implies Fb|[x_{n-1},b]_{\text{min}} = 0$ on $[x_{n-1}, b]$,  which implies that $L(Fb,P) = 0$.